# Dreamweaver - Repeated Codes

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, edit

I have around 6 or 7 pages in my site with repeated code. It's mostly repeated in the main and bottom menu. Can I use something in Dreamweaver to edit all the repeated code at the same time? Or maybe have the main code in a file that is imported by all the pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options depending on what you have available to you.

If you're using a server side technology, then using an include could work for you. You'd need to create a separate file that contains the common code and edit all of your pages and place the server include that references the common file in the place of the content. How to do that will depend on which server languages you have available to you.

Dreamweaver also has to non-server based capabilities that may be useful: templates and library items. Templates are meant to provide the structure for a page and have specific areas within a page based on the template (child page) that are editable. Library items are meant for blocks of code that are shared between multiple pages. You can use library items within templates, so the two aren't exclusive.

Based on that you have in your question, it appears that you may benefit from a library item. In Dreamweaver select the content you want shared.

Open the Assets panel (Window -> Assets), this may take a bit of time if you have a large site. Once the panel is open, switch to the Library category in the Assets panel (should be the bottom icon looks like a book). In your page select the shared content, then click the New Library Item button at the bottom of the assets panel second from left icon on the bottom right (or go to Modify -> Library -> Add Object to Library). The selected code should be wrapped with HTML comments indicating that it is now a library item. In the Assets panel you can give the content a name. On your other pages you can select the shared content and then in the Assets panel click the Insert button on the bottom left of the panel. Repeat as necessary (or if the content is exactly the same, you may be able to do a find and replace to chane the content into the comment wrapped content.

To edit a library item, select it in design view, and then open the Property Inspector (Window -> Properties) and click the Open button (or right click on the library item in design view and select Open Library Item). Make your edits and when you save the library item you should be asked if you want to update the pages that have the library item on it.

Library items are saves as .lbi files in a Library folder at the root of your site.

Many folks prefer server includes over library items, but for "static" files, Library items may be an acceptable solution.

For more info, check out the Dreamweaver CS5 help for library items: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7e49a.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. As result I have created the powershell script [Update-Lbi](https://github.com/mazzy-ax/Update-Lbi).